# How do I get the value of a checked radio button if my radio button is dynamic?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to retrieve the value selected by the user of radio buttons that are dynamic but I can't seem to do it. Here's the code:

Javascript for dynamic radio buttions:

```
function setupVisibilityElements() {
    jQuery.ajax({
        url: '/Api/Categories/GetVisibilityData',
        method: 'GET',
        dataType: "json",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        cache: false,
    }).done(function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        var visibilityList = data;
        var visibilityID = '';
        var visibilityName = '';
        var $radioElement = null;
        var oneVisbilityType = null;

        for (index = 0; index < visibilityList.length; index++) {
            oneVisbilityType = visibilityList[index];
            visibilityID = oneVisbilityType.visibilityId;
            visibilityName = oneVisbilityType.visibilityName;
            $radioElement = $('<input type="radio" value = "' + visibilityID + '" name="visibility" />');            
            $visibilityInputElement.append($radioElement);
            $radioElement = $('<span> ' + visibilityName + ' </br></span>');              
            $visibilityInputElement.append($radioElement);
        }
    })
}
```

Javascript for collecting of information:

```
var radioButtonChecker = document.getElementsByName('visibility');

for (var i = 0, length = radioButtonChecker.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (radioButtonChecker[i].checked) {
        console.dir(radioButtonChecker[i].value);
        break;
    }
}
```

EDIT:
I am trying to retrieve the values of the checked button, but it is not showing up. no errors.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/BfYoI.jpg

Comment: If its a part of `form`, form.serialize will give you all necessary values. If not, you can have class on them and check accordingly.

Comment: Your code seems to work fine. [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/2qprezL7/). Can you tell what exactly is the issue?

Comment: "I can't seem to do it". What have you tried? What precise problem are you having? Do you get an error message, or some other output?

Comment: I can't retrieve the values that the users have selected. I need to retrieve the values so that I can pass it into the SQL database, but right now I cannot do it. It's also not part of a >form. Here's the screenshot.
http://i.imgur.com/pTJY47X.jpg

Comment: @ShawnL. Have you checked that radiobuttonChecker.length is definitely > 0? I can't see that image, it's blocked (am at work). Can you paste it directly into the question?